# How to nest joins with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, join

I'm trying to behave. So, instead of using following SQL syntax:

```
select *
from   tableA INNER JOIN
       tableB on tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( tableC INNER JOIN tableD on tableC.tableD_id = tableD.id)
       on tableC.tableA_id = tableA.id
```

I'd like to use the CakePHP `model->find()`. This will let me use the `Paginator` too, since that will not work with custom SQL queries as far as I understand (unless you hardcode one single pagination query to the model which seems a little inflexible to me).

What I've tried so far:

```
/* inside tableA_controller.php, inside an action, e.g. "view" */
$this->paginate['recursive'] = -1; # suppress model associations for now
$this->paginate['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'tableB',
        'alias' => 'TableB',
        'type'  => 'inner',
        'conditions' => 'TableB.tableA_id = TableA.id',
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'tableC',
        'alias' => 'TableC',
        'type'  => 'left',
        'conditions' => 'TableC.tableA_id = TableA.id',
        'joins' = array( # this would be the obvious way to do it, but doesn't work
            array(
                'table' => 'tableD',
                'alias' => 'TableD',
                'type'  => 'inner',
                'conditions' => 'TableC.tableD_id = TableD.id'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

That is, nesting the joins into the structure. But that doesn't work (CakePHP just ignores the nested `'joins'` element which was kind of what I expected, but sad.

I have seen hints in comments on how to do subqueries (in the `where` clause) using a statement builder. Can a similar trick be used here?

Comment: Why does it have to be nested? Can't you just do the same thing with all the joins at the top level?

Comment: I wish I could, but the result is different: I want all the results from the top-level inner join with optional data tacked on from the nested inner join. If I flatten this, then I loose any rows in (TableA inner join TableB) that have no corresponding TableD...

Comment: Wow that's pretty complex. I'd probably try and extend find() somehow to add some extra parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can't. At least not with the syntax provided above and not with CakePHP 1.2.6. I went over the source (yay! to open source frameworks!) and found the file `cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php` which contains the code for the joins.

It all starts with `DboSource::renderStatement()` which does a shallow walk of the `$query['joins']` array, replacing those join definitions with SQL fragments via `DboSource::buildJoinStatement($join)`, which does some tidying up of the arguments (filling in blanks etc.) and then calls `DboSource::renderJoinStatement` to create the SQL fragment of a single join clause.

> *me:* That should be easy to fix!

I was told not to edit stuff in `cake/libs`, so instead I copied the file `dbo_source.php` to `app/models/datasources/` for editing. Then I took my axe and refactored the shallow walk of the `$query['joins']` array in `DboSource::renderStatement()` into a new method `DboSource::buildJoinStatementArray()` resulting in these two methods:

```
function buildStatement($query, $model) {
    $query = array_merge(array('offset' => null, 'joins' => array()), $query);

    # refactored (extract method) to make recursion easier
    $query['joins'] = $this->buildJoinStatementArray($query['joins']);

    return $this->renderStatement('select', array(
        'conditions' => $this->conditions($query['conditions'], true, true, $model),
        'fields' => implode(', ', $query['fields']),
        'table' => $query['table'],
        'alias' => $this->alias . $this->name($query['alias']),
        'order' => $this->order($query['order']),
        'limit' => $this->limit($query['limit'], $query['offset']),
        'joins' => implode(' ', $query['joins']),
        'group' => $this->group($query['group'])
    ));
}
/**
 * Replaces the join statement array syntax with SQL join clauses.
 */
function buildJoinStatementArray($joins) {
    if (!empty($joins)) {
        $count = count($joins);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if (is_array($joins[$i])) {
                $joins[$i] = $this->buildJoinStatement($joins[$i]); # $joins[$i] now contains something like "LEFT JOIN users As User on User.group_id = Group.id"
            }
        }
    }
    return $joins;
}
```

Once I had `DboSource::buildJoinStatementArray()`, it was time to change `DboSource::buildJoinStatement()` - all I did was added a check for `$data['joins']` and an alternative rendering method for that case:

```
function buildJoinStatement($join) {
    $data = array_merge(array(
        'type' => null,
        'alias' => null,
        'table' => 'join_table',
        'conditions' => array()
    ), $join);

    if (!empty($data['alias'])) {
        $data['alias'] = $this->alias . $this->name($data['alias']);
    }
    if (!empty($data['conditions'])) {
        $data['conditions'] = trim($this->conditions($data['conditions'], true, false));
    }

    # allow for nested joins
    if (!empty($data['joins']) and is_array($data['joins'])) {
        $data['joins'] = $this->buildJoinStatementArray($data['joins']);
        return $this->renderNestedJoinStatement($data);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->renderJoinStatement($data);
    }
}
```

The new `renderNestedJoinStatement()` method is pretty similar to `DboSource::renderJoinStatement()`:

```
/**
 * Renders a final SQL JOIN that contains nested join statements
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return string
 */
function renderNestedJoinStatement($data) {
    extract($data);
    $nestedJoins = implode(' ', $joins);
    return trim("{$type} JOIN ({$table} {$alias} {$nestedJoins})ON ({$conditions})");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting this right, you've got the following relationships (hopefully in your models):

```
TableA hasMany TableB.
TableA hasMany TableC.

TableB belongsTo TableA.

TableC belongsTo TableA.
TableC belongsTo TableD. (might be hasOne)

TableD hasMany TableC. (might be hasOne)
```

If you're using the Containable behaviour (I very much recommend it, and set it at app_model level for all models to inherit), I think you can do something like this...

```
$this->TableA->find(
  'all',
  array(
    'contain' => array(
      'TableB',
      'TableC' => array(
        'TableD'
      )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(...),
    'order' => array(...)
  )
);
```

If you need to pick specific fields, then you'll need to specify them in the contain parameter, for example here I restrict TableB's returned fields:

```
$this->TableA->find(
  'all',
  array(
    'contain' => array(
      'TableB' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'field_1',
          'field_2'
        ),
      ),
      'TableC' => array(
        'TableD'
      )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(...),
    'order' => array(...)
  )
);
```

The returned data should be like so:

```
  [0] => array(
    [TableA] => array(
      [id] => 12,
      [name] => 'Foo'
    ),
    [TableB] => array(
      [id] => 23,
      [table_a_id] => 12,
      [name] => 'Bah'
    ),
    [TableC] => array(
      [id] => 45,
      [table_a_id] => 12,
      [table_d_id] => 67,
      [name] => 'Woo',
      [TableD] => array(
        [0] => array(
          [id] => 67,
          [table_a_id] => 12,
          [name] => 'Wah'
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

However, I've never done this where the nested table is the parent of the container (TableD and TableC), so it might not work, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: This is not really what a left outer join does. I want to have null fields in [TableC] if the join (TableC x TableD) is empty. But adding nested joins to CakePHP was really easy, see my own answer.

Comment: Good point, glad you found a work around.
It would be great if you could check whether your solution is applicable to the 1.3.x branch and submit it as an fix for your use case, I'm sure there are plenty of people that would benefit.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you so much